# Probability of getting exactly 3 aces from drawing 7 cards by two methods

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is the problem number 4 from Tutorial question in 6.041/6.431: Probabilistic Systems Analysis from MIT OCW. Basically you are dealt 7 cards from well shuffled 52 cards deck, and asked to find the probability of getting exactly 3 aces.

One way I approached the problem is by multiplying the possible number of aces (4 choose 3) by the probability of getting 4 non-aces and 3 aces: P(A) = ${4\choose 3}$ $\frac{48}{52}$ $\frac{47}{51}$ $\frac{46}{50}$ $\frac{45}{49}$ $\frac{4}{48}$ $\frac{3}{47}$ $\frac{2}{46}$ $\approx$ $\mathrm{6.65}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\mathrm{10}^{-4}}$

Now, if I'm doing this by counting the possible number of ways of getting exactly 3 aces in 7 cards and dividing it with the possible number of ways of having 7 cards however, I get different result :
P(A) = $\frac{{4\choose 3}{48\choose 4}}{52\choose7}$ $\approx$ $\mathrm{5.82}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\mathrm{10}^{-3}}$

Can someone tell me in which part I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> One way I approached the problem is by multiplying the possible number of aces (4 choose 3) by the probability of getting 4 non-aces and 3 aces:

Don't multiply by the possible number of aces.   You are already accounting for that.

Rather, multiply by the possible number of *positions* for the aces among the seven cards.

$$\binom 7 3\dfrac{48\cdot 47\cdot 46\cdot 45\cdot ~~4\cdot ~~3\cdot ~~2}{52\cdot51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47\cdot 46}=\dfrac{7!}{4!~3!}\dfrac{\dfrac{48!}{44!}\dfrac{4!}{1!}}{\dfrac{52!}{45!}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{48!}{4!~44!}\dfrac{4!}{3!~1!}}{\dfrac{52!}{7!~45!}}=\dfrac{\dbinom {48}{4}\dbinom {4}{3}}{\dbinom {52}{7}}$$

---

$\tfrac{48\cdot 47\cdot 46\cdot 45\cdot ~~4\cdot ~~3\cdot ~~2}{52\cdot51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47\cdot 46}$ is the probability for obtaining four consecutive non-aces and then three consecutive aces when dealing cards out in order.

$\tbinom 73$ counts the permutations for 4 non-ace places and 3 ace places.

---

An alternate method is to evaluate the probability for three places for the aces to be among the first seven places in the deck (and one place among the later forty-five), when the four aces may be placed anywhere among the fifty two places without bias.$$\dfrac{\dbinom 73\dbinom {45}1}{\dbinom{52}{4}}$$